# Проблемы с App.config

Tags: c#, .net, config, app

При разработке простенького приложения (для себя) я добавил в секцию `appSettings` файла `App.config` 1 элемент:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="..." value="1;0;1;0"/>
</appSettings>
```

В этом элементе содержатся некоторые настройки. Но проблема в том, что секция `appSettings` - это `NamedValueCollection`, т. е. надпись выше равна

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="..." value="1"/>
    <add key="..." value="0"/>
    <add key="..." value="1"/>
    <add key="..." value="0"/>
</appSettings>
```

А мне нужно, чтобы `1;0;1;0` не "разделялось" на 4 значения, а было одним целым.
Как этого добиться?

Comment: `т. е. надпись выше равна` не равна

Comment: `мне нужно, чтобы 1;0;1;0 не "разделялось" на 4 значения, а было одним целым` ===> `<add key="..." value="1;0;1;0"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего там не разделяется

```
      <appSettings>
        <add key="key" value="1;0;1;0"/>
      </appSettings>

    var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

     Console.WriteLine(appSettings["key"]);  //1;0;1;0
```

Comment: Извините, у меня была не очевидная ошибка в коде. Всё должно работать (и работает) так, как вы сказали.